# Sfml Text Entered arrow keys

Tags: c++, sfml

I am making console style game in sfml. It's graphical interface but game itself contains console. I'm using Text Entered event for writing things in console but i also want to move the cursor (console cursor not mouse) with arrow keys. To be more specific in text entered event i am using event.text.unicode for key value. But arrow keys unicode values not working in my pc. I used 37 for left arrow, 39 for right arrow but it doesn't work. This is my console's key process function.

```
void Console::update(int unicode) {
    if(unicode == 8) { // Backspace
        deleteLast();
    } else if(unicode == 13) { // Enter
        newLine();
    } else if(unicode == 37) { // Left arrow key
        currentX--;
        std::cout << "Left arrow" << std::endl;
    } else if(unicode == 39) { // Right arrow key
        currentX++;
        std::cout << "Right arrow" << std::endl;
    } else { // Normal characters
        buffer[(currentY == 0) ? currentX : (currentY * maxColumn) + currentX] = (char)unicode;
        currentX++;
        if(currentX == maxColumn - 1) {
            newLine();
        }
        std::cout << "[KEY TYPED] X: " << currentX << " Y: " << currentY << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Edit: I think i solved. I used KeyPressed event for handling special keys. And TextEntered for handling normal characters.

Comment: What is the significance of 37 and 39? What do those numbers have to do with the left and right arrow keys?

Comment: IMHO, a `switch` statement would be more readable.

Comment: Have you verified, by using the debugger, that the key codes are correct?  My understanding is that left arrow and right arrow require more than one character to represent and would be outside the ASCII range if pressed.

Comment: You could use `'<'` and `'>'` to make you code more readable rather than numbers.

Answer (score 1):

For those having the same problem:
From an Event type variable, first check if its a keyboard event

```
if(event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
```

**Then** check if its an arrow:

```
if(event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up)
    //do stuff
if(event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Down)
    //do stuff
```